# Problema com Printar números repetidos em C

Tags: c

A questão pedia que eu fizesse um código que armazenasse 10 valores inteiros, verificasse se havia algum numero repetido, e se houvesse, printasse os números repetidos, mas o meu código ou printa alguns numeros repetidos mais de uma vez, ou printa uma única vez. Como posso corrigir isto?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10
int main (){
    int i,Vetor[N],aux[N]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},count=0,j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("insira o %dº número\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&Vetor[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
            if(Vetor[i]==Vetor[j]){
                count++;
                aux[i]=Vetor[i];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("existem %d números iguais\n",count);
    printf("os números que aparecem repetidos são:\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(aux[i]!=0)
            printf("%d\n",aux[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Antes de colocar na variavel `aux` precisa de verificar se ja existe la algum, terá de criar uma função que verifique isso. Da maneira que está a fazer está a colocar os numeros todos para a variavel `aux`

Comment: Bem mais "simples" e eficiente é ordenar o array utilizando `qsort` (ou uma copia do mesmo com `memcpy` se quiser manter o original) e depois utilizar um *loop* normal para percorrer e indicar os que se repetem que irão ficar todos seguidos.

Answer (score 1):

Bem uma solução possível é utilizar booleano para resolver o problema, basta incluir no começo do código `#include <stdbool.h>` e declarar uma variável bool, para verificar se já existe ou não dentro do aux o mesmo número, caso exista ele não vai adicionar novamente ao aux, evitando assim os números repetidos no vetor aux, aqui está o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 10
int main (){
    int i,Vetor[N],aux[N]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},count=0,j;
    bool repete;//Variável que verifica se existe ou não o número no vetor aux
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("insira o %dº número\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&Vetor[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
            if(Vetor[i]==Vetor[j]){
                repete=false;//Definir inicialmente como falso
                for(int k=0; k<i; k++)//Pecorre o vetor aux
                {
                    if(aux[k]==Vetor[i]){//Se já existir fica verdadeiro
                       repete=true;
                    }
                }
                if(!repete){//Se nao existir no vetor ele é adicionado
                    aux[i]=Vetor[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int l=0; l<N; l++)//Verifica quantos números repetidos existem no vetor
        if(aux[l]!=0)
            count++;
    printf("existem %d números iguais\n",count);
    printf("os números que aparecem repetidos são:\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(aux[i]!=0)
            printf("%d\n",aux[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Não entendi ao certo se você buscava o total de repetições dos números ou quantos números eram repetidos, então fiz pelo último caso.

Answer (score 1):

Há um erro de lógica no seu algoritmo, quando passa por esse trecho

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
        if(Vetor[i]==Vetor[j]){
            count++;
            aux[i]=Vetor[i];
        }
    }
}
```

O que acontece é que ele vai checar se na lista de número que você botou, realmente há números repetidos, mas o que talvez você não tenha reparado é que e se houver mais de uma repetição?

Imagine a seguinte situação:

```
2 4 8 2 9 2 0 1 3 2
```

Observe que o número 2 se repetiu 4 vezes.

Quando seu código for avaliar esses 10 números ele vai identificar a seguinte resposta, considerando o o retorno do if como true (1) ou false (0)

```
2 4 8 2 9 2 0 1 3 2
- 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Então ele identificou 3 repetições do número 2, adicionou ele ao vetor aux e prosseguimos no código, mas pouco depois você passará pelo 2 novamente, quando o código chegar no 4 digito, ele vai avaliar novamente

```
2 4 8 2 9 2 0 1 3 2
      - 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

A questão agora é que o 2 já foi analisado, não teria motivo para ser contabilizado novamente, e provavelmente esse é o motivo de imprimir o mesmo número mais de uma vez no final.

O que falta é fazer uma exceção para pular os números já repetidos, algo como:

```
int rep = 0, k;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
        if(Vetor[i]==Vetor[j]){
            // Faz uma busca no aux para ver se esse numero ja foi analisado
            for(k=0;k<N;k++){
                if(aux[k]!=0 && aux[k]==Vetor[i]){
                    // Salva nessa variavel se esse numero ja foi usado
                    rep = 1
                }
            }
            // Se nao foi usado, salva normalmente
            if(rep==0){
                count++;
                aux[i]=Vetor[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida pergunte, abraço!